# How do I change the recommended C# variable naming convention?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I've been naming private member variables (especially those that are backing fields for properties) with a leading underscore forever. VS 2012 is a little gripey about this though.

Ex:

```
private int _MyVal;
public int MyVal 
{
  get { return _MyVal;}
  set { _MyVal = value;}
}
```

How do I get VS2012 to quit it's Kvetching or even better actively suggest my preferred naming convention? (Of note, I obviously don't want to do this for method parameters, public fields or members as AFAIK that does not conform to the .net calling conventions.)

Comment: Use a Tool like ReSharper.

Comment: @UweKeim - I guess it is the problem, not a solution... I'm not sure VS itself by default complains about naming at all.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff926074.aspx

Comment: I appreciate you have been doing this "forever", but maybe now is time to stop? You can replace all that code with just `public int MyVal { get; set; }` and have it functionally identical. Don't make work for yourself...

Comment: By the way, if you use `_myVal` instead of `_MyVal`, I think it'll stop griping. Private variables should start with an underscore and a lowercase letter.

Comment: David, for auto properties I do exactly what you are mentioning, but for INotifyPropertyChanged objects I need backing fields to do signaling when properties are updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll simply direct you to this other question: [C# Coding Standards Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497129/c-sharp-coding-standards-tool)

To sum up it suggests, StyleCop, Resharper and FxCop among other things.